# error message on plug-in Customize Page Code in Adobe DTM

Tags: plugins, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am trying to track the number of visits in Adobe DTM using the getVisitNum plug-in. The Library is managed by Adobe, therefor I put the plug-ins in Custom Page Code. I have the following code as per Adobe documentation:

// Plugin Config

```
s.usePlugins = true;
s.doPlugins = s_doPlugins;

function s_doPlugins(s) 
{ 
// get visit number within a month  
s.eVarXX = s.getVisitNum('m');
}

/*
* Plugin: getVisitNum - version 3.0
*/
s.getVisitNum=new Function("tp","c","c2",""
+"var s=this,e=new Date,cval,cvisit,ct=e.getTime(),d;if(!tp){tp='m';}"
+"if(tp=='m'||tp=='w'||tp=='d'){eo=s.endof(tp),y=eo.getTime();e.setTi"
+"me(y);}else {d=tp*86400000;e.setTime(ct+d);}if(!c){c='s_vnum';}if(!"
+"c2){c2='s_invisit';}cval=s.c_r(c);if(cval){var i=cval.indexOf('&vn="
+"'),str=cval.substring(i+4,cval.length),k;}cvisit=s.c_r(c2);if(cvisi"
+"t){if(str){e.setTime(ct+1800000);s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return str;}els"
+"e {return 'unknown visit number';}}else {if(str){str++;k=cval.substri"
+"ng(0,i);e.setTime(k);s.c_w(c,k+'&vn='+str,e);e.setTime(ct+1800000);"
+"s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return str;}else {s.c_w(c,e.getTime()+'&vn=1',e)"
+";e.setTime(ct+1800000);s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return 1;}}");
s.dimo=new Function("m","y",""
+"var d=new Date(y,m+1,0);return d.getDate();");
s.endof=new Function("x",""
+"var t=new Date;t.setHours(0);t.setMinutes(0);t.setSeconds(0);if(x=="
+"'m'){d=s.dimo(t.getMonth(),t.getFullYear())-t.getDate()+1;}else if("
+"x=='w'){d=7-t.getDay();}else {d=1;}t.setDate(t.getDate()+d);return "
+"t;");`
```

I am getting a RefferenceError: s is not defined

I am not receiving the error for my other plug-in which work practically the same way. Any idea what is going wrong and how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: If you already have `s.doPlugins`,  `s.usePlugins`, and `s_doPlugins`, as well as other plugins included within the AA tool's **Customize Page Code** code box, and *without this new plugin, your code works without error*, and what you posted above is a simplified version of it showing only this new plugin, then at face value, throwing a new plugin into the mix shouldn't give you that error.  Which means that your issue is deeper, and your existing setup in fact does not work. IOW, in order to get that error, it must have existed before throwing this new plugin into the mix

Comment: So, you will need to provide more information about how you have everything setup, or what else you changed in the process, if you are absolutely certain it worked before you added it.

Comment: In Library Management, the code configurations are set to be managed by Adobe. The setups are kept as simple as possible to prevent errors, no changes made. It works perfectly when I remove s.eVarXX = s.getVisitNum('m').

Comment: If what you have posted here is accurate, and the only thing you change is to remove or comment out this line: `s.eVarXX = s.getVisitNum('m');`  and it works perfectly, then either a) the error already existed independent of this (what I previously said), or b) your setup and/or posted code is not as you say it is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting s.doPlugins = s_doPlugins too early. 
Try setting this after the do_Plugins function:

```
s.usePlugins = true;

function s_doPlugins(s) {

// get visit number within a month  
s.eVarXX = s.getVisitNum('m');

}  

s.doPlugins=s_doPlugins;

//Begin Plugin Code

/*
* Plugin: getVisitNum - version 3.0
*/
s.getVisitNum=new Function("tp","c","c2",""
+"var s=this,e=new Date,cval,cvisit,ct=e.getTime(),d;if(!tp){tp='m';}"
+"if(tp=='m'||tp=='w'||tp=='d'){eo=s.endof(tp),y=eo.getTime();e.setTi"
+"me(y);}else {d=tp*86400000;e.setTime(ct+d);}if(!c){c='s_vnum';}if(!"
+"c2){c2='s_invisit';}cval=s.c_r(c);if(cval){var i=cval.indexOf('&vn="
+"'),str=cval.substring(i+4,cval.length),k;}cvisit=s.c_r(c2);if(cvisi"
+"t){if(str){e.setTime(ct+1800000);s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return str;}els"
+"e {return 'unknown visit number';}}else {if(str){str++;k=cval.substri"
+"ng(0,i);e.setTime(k);s.c_w(c,k+'&vn='+str,e);e.setTime(ct+1800000);"
+"s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return str;}else {s.c_w(c,e.getTime()+'&vn=1',e)"
+";e.setTime(ct+1800000);s.c_w(c2,'true',e);return 1;}}");
s.dimo=new Function("m","y",""
+"var d=new Date(y,m+1,0);return d.getDate();");
s.endof=new Function("x",""
+"var t=new Date;t.setHours(0);t.setMinutes(0);t.setSeconds(0);if(x=="
+"'m'){d=s.dimo(t.getMonth(),t.getFullYear())-t.getDate()+1;}else if("
+"x=='w'){d=7-t.getDay();}else {d=1;}t.setDate(t.getDate()+d);return "
+"t;");`
```

One last thing: I don't have this handy, but double check the configuration of getVisitNum and make sure you're not missing an argument.

Comment: This is not the problem. Firstly, (s)he already said it works fine before introducing the plugin. More importantly though, order for this doesn't matter, because [function declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).

Comment: @CrayonViolent Order is certainly important here given how / when DTM loads the AA tool and then effectively destroys the s object after it runs. If it were global in nature (in DTM), I would agree with you.  I personally would take a closer look at how s.getVisitNum is called within do_Plugins

Comment: None of that is relevant if his code is within the same block (which his post implies). If the `s` object gets overwritten, order is still unimportant within this posted code, because the whole thing is overwritten. Re-ordering that code isn't going to save it from being overwritten at that point

Comment: I tried that already, but it still doesn't work. It seems that the reference to s.dimo in s.endof goes wrong. The new error message is "s.dimo is not a function".

Comment: I also don't think it's the order. It looks more as a plugin issue.